# Combo Box Data Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Hopefully someone has seen this before and can see my mistake:

I am binding a combo box selected value to a data set and the first time I change the combo box selected value, it does not update in the data set i.e. the values don't match. If I change the selected value a second time it works as expected and my data set updates to match the combo box.

I am also using a second data set for the Data Source which populates the list of items with text (for the user) but provides an index to save in the first data set.

```
comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", dataView1, "mode", true));
comboBox.DataSource = dataView2;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "list_str.str_text";
comboBox.ValueMember = "list_str.index";
```

Any idea why the data set does not update the first time the selected value changes?

EDIT: I may not have been clear originally but I'm not binding directly to the data set - I am using a data view since I have multiple tables in the data set. Is it possible to use the data view to automatically save back to the data set? Should I close this and open a new question?

Comment: How are you testing the dataset value? Without additional code, the actual update will not occur until focus leaves the combo box.

Comment: Yes I automatically change the focus using the SelectionChangeCommitted event and I am checking the value using the debugger when the data set attempts to save. Since my initial question, I added an extra text box and gave it the same binding but to display only the index. It has the correct value when the form loads but never updates when I change the selected value of the combo box. I am doing something wrong with the binding it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` instead.

http://devpinoy.org/blogs/joeycalisay/archive/2005/11/23/Combobox-SelectedIndexChanged-vs-SelectionChangeCommitted.aspx

SelectedIndexChanged 
* raised when DataSource is set
* raised when SelectedIndex is set programmatically

SelectionChangeCommitted
* not raised when DataSource is set
* not raised when SelectedIndex is set programmatically

Comment: That was one of my first thoughts but the SelectionChangeCommitted event is being triggered and completes the necessary change of focus to validate the control.

Comment: Then this is getting more interesting. Sorry for not being able to help. Still I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I may not have been clear in my original question, but I am not binding directly to the data set. I am using a data view since I have multiple tables. I think these work as their name implies and you can only VIEW the data in the original data set and it does not automatically save changes. I added a line to save any new values to the original data set and now everything seems to work every time!